# how to get username who make an request to lita

Tags: deployment, jenkins, chat, slack-api, slack

I'd like to know how to get username who posted in slack channel. 
It seems to possible to get user information through Slack API. (https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks). In our office, we use slack to deploy via slack by using lita(https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) and jenkins.  I want to prevent non-developers can make request of deploying. However, I can't figure it out how to get username through Slack API. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In lita, the sender of the message is accessible via `@response.user`. 
You could also manage the list of users who are allowed to deploy via [group authorization](http://docs.lita.io/getting-started/usage/#authorization-groups)  as is done in [lita-retro](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/lita-retro):

`route /retro\s+clear/i, :clear, command: true, restrict_to: :retro_admins, help: {
  "retro clear" => t("help.clear_value")
}`